# How to Drop Duplicates if the rows is present more than twice?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with around 50MB in size. This is what the sample DataFrame looks like:

```
TITLE     DESCRIPTION
android   android@email.com
python    python@email.com
android   android@outlook.com
android   android@email.com
Php       php@email.com
```

I am trying to remove all the duplicates from the dataframe **only if the TITLE is occurred more than 2 times**, so the `output` will look like this :

```
TITLE     DESCRIPTION
android   android@email.com
python    python@email.com
android   android@outlook.com
Php       php@email.com
```

This is the code i am using right now :

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='TITLE',  inplace=True, keep=False)
```

But, the issue is it removes all the duplicates and only keeps a `single` occurrence of the Title, how can i make it to remove only if a title has occured `more than 2 times`, please post the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try [`groupby` + `cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create a sequential counter per `TITLE`, then select the rows where the value of this counter is less than `1`

```
df[df.groupby('TITLE').cumcount().le(1)]
```

---

```
     TITLE          DESCRIPTION
0  android    android@email.com
1   python     python@email.com
2  android  android@outlook.com
4      Php        php@email.com
```

Comment: Excellent answer Buddy ! Huge thanks. I am trying to understand this part of the doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html , but couldnt quite got it. Can you please explain whats happening here